# Creating multiple FileWriter objects in a loop

Tags: java, loops, iteration, filewriter

I need to use this loop  to create different text files with different output. Right now it creates 3 files which look like this:

```
texts1.txt = some text
texts2.txt = texts1.txt + some text
texts3.txt = texts2.txt + some text
```

My idea was to create multiple `FileWriter` class objects by naming the object `Fw[it]` so that there would be as many ojects as I need. Unfortunately in java I can't do that. 
Is there any alternative way to create multiple `FileWriter` objects in a loop?

```
int count = 3;
for (int it = 0; it < count; it++) {
String xxx = "texts" + it + ".txt";
FileWriter Fw = new FileWriter(xxx);
Collections.shuffle(list);
Fw.write(met.prnt(list,temp));
Fw.close();
}
```

Okay it compiles and runs however it still has the same problem: it creates 3 files which look like this:

```
texts1.txt = some text
texts2.txt = texts1.txt + some text
texts3.txt = texts2.txt + some text
```

However, it should be like this:

```
texts1.txt = some text
texts2.txt = some text
texts3.txt = some text
```

Right now the code looks like this:

```
int count = 3;
for (int it = 0; it < count; it++) {
Collections.shuffle(list);
String xxx = "texts" + it + ".txt";
FileWriter hah[] = new FileWriter[count];
hah[it] = new FileWriter(xxx,false);
hah[it].write(met.prnt(list,temp));
hah[it].flush();
hah[it].close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes create a FileWriter[] writers = new FileWriter[count] and put each writer in its own slot

Comment: Thanks but i still get the same problem it creates 3 files which look like this: texts1.txt = some text, texts2.txt = texts1.txt + some text and texts3.txt = texts2.txt + some text. However it should be like this: texts1.txt = some text , texts2.txt = some text , texts3.txt = some text

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not behave as you describe. It is not even possible. The line that does the writing doesn't make any use of the filename variable `xxx`. I also don't understand why you made the second version which creates the array of FileWriters, as you are still only using one at a time. Especially as you are creating the array inside the loop.